# jquery-cropper how to get width and height values from select option menu?

Tags: jquery, onchange

How can i get width and height values from dropdown? Normally if I define width and height values inside `data:{` manually it works but cropper width and height values are not changing from select option menu.

Ok i edit the cropper.
There are different values in option menu, if selected a value the Cropper area need to change which value come from select menu.

What's going wrong?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/cropperjs/dist/cropper.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://doganozcine.com/dosyalar/main.css">



    <div class="container mt-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <!-- <h3>Demo:</h3> -->
                <div class="img-container">
                    <img id="image" src="https://fengyuanchen.github.io/jquery-cropper/images/picture.jpg" alt="Picture">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="mb-3">
                            <select id="bolumler" name="seolink" class="form-control form-control-sm" required>
                              <option value="">Bölüm seçiniz</option>
                              <option value="0,0">Free</option>
                              <option value="534,304,#about">Hakkımızda</option>
                              <option value="690,530,#blog">Blog</option>
                              <option value="1194,495,#facts">Rakamsal İstatistikler</option>
                              <option value="808,608,#portfolio">Ürünler</option>
                              <option value="270,93,#clients">Referansların Logoları</option>
                              <option value="400,400,#testimonials">Müşteri Görüşleri</option>                   
                                <option value="510,400,#team">Bizim Takım/Çalışanlar</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <style>
                        .TeklibutonGenislikleri {
                            width:90px!important;
                            text-align: left;
                        }
                    </style>                
                    <style>
                        .ikilibutonGenislikleri {
                            width:45px!important;
                            text-align: center;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="docs-preview clearfix">
                            <div class="img-preview preview-md"></div>

                            <div class="docs-buttons">

                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <label class="TeklibutonGenislikleri btn btn-primary btn-upload btn-sm" for="inputImage" title="Upload image file">
                                        <input type="file" class="sr-only" id="inputImage" name="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif,.bmp,.tiff">
                                        <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="false" title="Bilgisayarınızdan Fotoğraf Yükleyin">
                                            <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Yükle
                                        </span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm TeklibutonGenislikleri" data-method="getCroppedCanvas" title="Seçili bölümü kırp">
                                        <i class="fa fa-crop"></i> Kırp
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm TeklibutonGenislikleri" data-method="reset" title="Sıfırla">
                                        <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="false" title="">
                                            <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Sıfırla
                                        </span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ikilibutonGenislikleri" data-method="zoom" data-option="0.1" title="Yaklaştır">
                                    <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="false" title="">
                                      <span class="fa fa-search-plus"></span>
                                    </span>
                                  </button>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ikilibutonGenislikleri" data-method="zoom" data-option="-0.1" title="Uzaklaştır">
                                    <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="false" title="">
                                      <span class="fa fa-search-minus"></span>
                                    </span>
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                                

                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm TeklibutonGenislikleri" data-method="setDragMode" data-option="move" type="button" title="Move">
                                      <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Sürükle" data-original-title="">
                                       <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt"></i> Taşı&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                      </span>
                                </button>

                                <div class="btn-group">
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ikilibutonGenislikleri" data-method="rotate" data-option="-45" title="Sola döndür">
                                    <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="false" title="">
                                      <span class="fa fa-rotate-left"></span>
                                    </span>
                                  </button>
                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ikilibutonGenislikleri" data-method="rotate" data-option="45" title="Sağa döndür">
                                    <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="false" title="">
                                      <span class="fa fa-rotate-right"></span>
                                    </span>
                                  </button>
                                </div>

                                <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ikilibutonGenislikleri" data-method="scaleX" data-option="-1" title="Yatay Çevir">
                                    <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="">
                                      <span class="fa fa-arrows-h"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </button>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary bt-sm ikilibutonGenislikleri" data-method="scaleY" data-option="-1" title="Dikey çevir">
                                    <span class="docs-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="">
                                      <span class="fa fa-arrows-v"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </button>
                                </div>



                                <!-- Show the cropped image in modal -->
                                <div class="modal fade docs-cropped" id="getCroppedCanvasModal" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="getCroppedCanvasTitle" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="getCroppedCanvasTitle">Kırpılan</h5>
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="modal-body"></div>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Vazgeç</button>
                                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="download" href="javascript:void(0);" download="cropped.jpg">İndir</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://doganozcine.com/dosyalar/cropper.js"></script>

    <script src="http://doganozcine.com/dosyalar/jquery-cropper.js"></script>

    <script src="http://doganozcine.com/dosyalar/main.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var genislik;
            var yukseklik;
            
          $('#bolumler').on('change', function() {

            var degerler = ( this.value );
            //console.log(degerler);
              
            var bolumlerDizi = degerler.split(',');
            genislik = bolumlerDizi[0];    
            yukseklik = bolumlerDizi[1];
  
            console.log("Cropper must width!: " + genislik);
            console.log("Cropper must height!: " + yukseklik);
      });  
      
        //var genislik = 800; 
        //var yukseklik = 200; 


        var options = {


            data: {

                width: genislik,
                height: yukseklik,

                
            },

            /*
            minCropBoxWidth: genislik,
            minCropBoxHeight: yukseklik,
            minCanvasWidth: genislik,
            minCanvasHeight: yukseklik,
              
            minContainerWidth: genislik,        
            minContainerHeight: yukseklik,
            //responsive:true,*/

            aspectRatio: genislik/yukseklik,
            viewMode: 1,
            restore: false,
            guides: false,
            center: false,
            dragCrop:false,
            highlight: false,
            cropBoxMovable: true,
            cropBoxResizable: true,
            rotatable:false,
            zoomable:false,
            preview: '.img-preview',
            
            //strict:true,
            //draggable:true,

            crop: function(e) {
                // $dataX.val(Math.round(e.detail.x));
                //$dataY.val(Math.round(e.detail.y));
                //$dataHeight.val(Math.round(e.detail.height));
                //$dataWidth.val(Math.round(e.detail.width));
                //$dataRotate.val(e.detail.rotate);
                //$dataScaleX.val(e.detail.scaleX);
                //$dataScaleY.val(e.detail.scaleY);
            },
               
        };
          
            
    </script>
```

Comment: The `genislik` and `yukseklik` variables are not defined when you define `options`. Also, you'll likely need to reinitialize the cropper from within your `onchange` handler. Can you include the code for the cropper so we can see a functional example of the problem?

Comment: ok i updated  functional example